# Handling events cross-project with Inheritance

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, c++-cli

I've got 2 projects;
- My application written in C++ with some project files set to use /clr
- My C# WPF control library which contains some forms

In the C++ application I load the forms from the C# dll and display them in an STAThread, while I run some other native stuff in the background.

I would like to handle form events from the C# form in my C++ application. Here's my code for launching the form;

```
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Controls;
using namespace MyProject::Interface::Views;

public ref class MyProjectApplication : public Application
{
};

[STAThread]
void ManagedMain()
{
    CLILicenseView^ winLicenseAgreement = gcnew CLILicenseView();

    MyProjectApplication^ MyProjectCLI = gcnew MyProjectApplication();
    MyProjectCLI->Run(winLicenseAgreement);
}
```

My original form is called "License.xaml" and I tried to inherit it and override events because I thought it might help me in handling the events but I've got no idea what I'm doing.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Controls;
using namespace MyProject::Interface::Views;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class CLILicenseView : License
    {
        public void CLILicenseView()
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way, and if not how can I handle form events (ie: button clicks) from my C++ application?

Comment: is this managed c++ ? (you talk about other 'native' stuff)

Comment: Yes, it'll be managed. There are some native files in my C++ project, but they are irrelevant to the problem I'm having since the managed and native part are seperate.

Comment: in `License`; have your controls be declared as `protected` members OR create `protected virtual void` methods in `License` which are raised on form events (e.g. `btnX.Click += OnBtnXClick;` where `OnBtnXClick` is a `protected virtual void` method within `License`), then override the methods in `CLILicenseView`.

Comment: @jberger I can't seem to make it work I get 2 errors related to my syntax and I can't find out what's going wrong. Here's the code I'm trying to do to ovveride the event [link](http://pastebin.com/T4XyY4g5)

Comment: I fixed one by adding a ; on the end of my class decl, but theres still an annoying syntax error `Error 1 error C2144: syntax error : 'MyProject::CLILicenseView' should be preceded by ':'  12 1 MyProject
`

Comment: Fixed all the syntax errors, post an answer and I'll select it as correct if you'd like.

Comment: Hmm, that didnt really fix my problem because it physically relocated the execution scope of the class to my own assembly which means it no longer loads the form from the right location. Is there a way I can ovveride only some methods of the original function from another assembly without creating a new class? @jberger

Comment: `relocated the execution scope of the class to my own assembly which means it no longer loads the form from the right location`. which `class`? which location DOES it load from and which location SHOULD it load from?

Comment: it may be easier to just create a gist (on github) for this question and just update those files..

Comment: In `License.xaml.cs`, btnAccept_Click method should be: `protected **virtual** void btnAccept_Click`

Comment: @jberger The problem I have now is that I can see the inheritance working, except when I create my class `CLILicenseView^ winLicenseAgreement = gcnew CLILicenseView();` the class seems to now want to `InitializeComponent()` in the C++ assembly rather than the C# assembly, causing `InitializeComponent` to fail loading the form .xaml files and resources.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10518/discussion-between-kvanberendonck-and-jberger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think composition is the right tool here, instead of inheritance. In the C++/CLI project that I've worked on (just a class library, no UI) the ref class usually holds an unmanged pointer to the C++ business logic. When a user wants to interact with the business logic they  call a managed method which then calls into the unmanged code via the pointer. In your case, when the Form wants to interact with the unmanaged code it should call back into `MyProjectApplication` which in turn calls into your unmanaged code.